# JSON.Net and typed datasets

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

Does anyone know if JSON.net can serialize/deserialize typed datasets in asp.net? Or if not, are there any other options to do this?

I looked around but couldn't find anything in the JSON.net docs that explicitly said 'yes' to support of typed datasets.

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming yes. I have used a version of JSON.net with a typed collection and it worked very well.

Comment: @ern: was the typed collection a typed DataSet?

Comment: @John: no, it wasn't. It was a collection of a custom object.